# Proving that a sequence is in GP

Tags: sequences-and-series

If **a,b,c** are in an **AP** and **a,b,d** are in a **GP**, then 
***a , a-b , d-c*** are in

a)AP

b)GP

c)HP

d)None of the above

This question recently came up in an MCQ exam I gave. I marked **b)** by taking examples( 2,4,6,8) and got it right.

But isn't there any mathematically rigorous way to prove this?

Comment: I assume AP, GP, HP stand for arithmetic, geometric, harmonic progression, and MCQ might be something like math contest quarterly?

Comment: MCQ stands for Multiple Choice Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $c=2b-a$ and $d=\dfrac{b^2}a$. Hence, we have
$$(a,a-b,d-c) = \left(a,a-b, \dfrac{b^2}a-(2b-a)\right) = \left(a,a-b,\dfrac{b^2+a^2-2ab}a\right) = \left(a,a-b,\dfrac{(a-b)^2}a\right)$$

Hence, the numbers are in GP, with common ratio $\dfrac{a-b}a$.

Comment: You did it really quickly.I never thought of plugging in the values.I was always trying to derive it through retro analysis.Thank you :)